# ExpandableListView with multiple images and text in header

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to use `ExpandableListView` on my app following the tutorial at:

https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

But, in my case, my header on each row would have 2 textViews and 2 imageviews, so, looking at the `ExpandableListAdapter class` used in the tutorial, there is this method:

```
@Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }
```

and this method is being called in `getGroupView` method like this:

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        // rest of the code
```

In the example, there is only one TextView on header, but in my case I have 2 TextViews and 2 ImageViews, so in this line:

```
String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
```

How would I know which text is which?, and the same for the images, how to make the difference between one image or the other??

Comment: one approach (might be wrong, and not implemented, just an idea), create `MyOwnHeader` class model for the header row, and make `getGroup` return `MyOwnHeader` for the given position???.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create POJO class and create ArrayList of that pojo class. Something like this

```
public class HeaderData {

    String title;
    String strImageURL;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getStrImageURL() {
        return strImageURL;
    }

    public void setStrImageURL(String strImageURL) {
        this.strImageURL = strImageURL;
    }
}
```

Now create  List like this `private List<HeaderData> _listDataHeader;` So now you just need to set both title and Image URL and you can easily get while binding header.

Comment: yes, thanks!, I think my first thought was right, I think I answered myself with my first comment on my question, but still thanks!